# How do i get a list of Vm in a recourse group

Tags: azure, powershell

Im trying to get all Vms in a resource group then send every element to a function

```
$a = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName Test2 | ft Name
foreach($output in $a) {Stop-AzRmVM -ResourceGroupName "Test2" -Name $output}
```

Im getting this error message

Start-AzureRmVM : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Name'. Specified 
method is not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Anish K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4111181/anish-k) is correct about the `Name` parameter expecting a String, not an array of objects.

However, you should also remove the `| ft Name` because that is only for outputting stuff to console.

I'd use a `ForEach-Object` here like this (untested):

```
Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName 'Test2' | ForEach-Object {
    $_ | Stop-AzRmVM
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the error, you are passing an object[] instead of string. Your function Stop-AzRmVm expects string for **Name** parameter.

Changes your script like below:

```
$a = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName Test2 | ft Name
foreach($output in $a) {Stop-AzRmVM -ResourceGroupName "Test2" -Name $output.Name}
```

Comment: Im still getting an error message saying :" Stop-AzureVM : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Name'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is 
not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:53 char:71"